# Sagt man "Das Reisen bildet" oder "Reisen bildet"?

Tags: idiom

Sagt man "Das Reisen bildet" oder "Reisen bildet"?
Kann der bestimmte Artikel in dem Spruch sein? Oder muss er/darf er nicht?

Answer (score 2):

Beides ist möglich. Der bestimmte Artikel wirkt wie ein *kleines Demonstrativpronomen*.

Dies sind zwei nebeneinanderstehende Fakten:

> Urlaub ist gut für den Geist. Reisen bildet.

Hier zeigt man hingegen mit einem Finger auf das Wort *Reisen*:

> Urlaub ist gut für den Geist. Das Reisen bildet.

Dadurch wird ein Zusammenhang hergestellt: Das Reisen ist der Teil am Urlaub, der gut für den Geist ist, weil er bildet.

Comment: Im allgemeinen findet man solche Ausdrücke aber eher ohne Artikel -  "Schwimmen ist gesund.", "Tanzen macht Spaß." - speziell wenn man sie als ein Art feststehende Weisheiten äußert.